# Loop over range in Django Html Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In my django template I want to replicate a line by the number of quantities like the following:

[image]

Something like repeating Material Request 67 14 times, 34 15 times and so on

for that I have retrieved quantity in a list like following:

```
d_docket = AllotmentDocket.objects.filter(parent_company = client_pk.pk, transaction_date__range =[start, end]).order_by('-transaction_date')

quan = list(d_docket.values_list('product1_quantity', flat=True))
```

which gives:

[14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 15, 13, 6, 15, 15, 10, 15, 15, 15, 7, 8]

But how can I loop over range of each element of `quan` in django template ?

Current Template:

```
{% for i in query %}
        <tr>


            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.owner }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.pk }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.flow }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.kit }}</td>
        </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give as context your `query` and also `quan`. Then, at each iteration of your current forloop use `quan[forloop.counter0]` as follows:

```
{% for i in query %}
    {% with index=forloop.counter0 %}
    {% with ''|center:quan.index as range %}
    {% for _ in range %}
        <tr>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.owner }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.pk }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.flow }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ i.sales_order.kit }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I go this error:  Could not parse the remainder: '(forloop.counter0)' from '''|center:quan.(forloop.counter0)'

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 102: 'endwith', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
I am using proper ` {% endwith %}`

Comment: @RahulSharma can you try the new edit? We'll do our best to find it together ;p

Comment: the new edit gives `'with' received an invalid token: "''|center:quan.index"`

Comment: @RahulSharma I think I got it now. My previous solution was correct but I forgot a `%`. Can you try again with the edited answer?

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
I got this error

Comment: @RahulSharma On which line is this caused? Try some stuff to investigate what the problem is.